# IE 7 & 8 drop down issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am new to building sites so go easy on me :) I am having an issue with IE 7 and 8 with a css dropdown menu. Works fine in others browsers.

Here is the css I am struggling with:

```
.nav-item {
    display: inline-block; padding: 25px 10px 25px 20px; top: 0px;
    font-size: 14px; position: relative; 
    /* IE7 FIX*/
    zoom: 1; *display: inline;
}

.nav-item .dropdown {
    display: none;position: absolute; top: 62px; text-align: left;  left: 27px; 
    padding: 5px 10px 8px 5px; background: #343434; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; z-index: 11; 
}

#header-wrapper {width: 990px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; position: relative; z-index: 9;  overflow: visible;}
```

The drop down only seems to stay within the header and will not overhang even though it's position is absolute, as if the header-wrapper has overflow: hidden;

Any ideas or suggestions would be great, thanks!

Adam

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: Hi Pekka, I have amended the post. Sorry i am really new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please remove  `.gradient class menuitem`.

one small issues   `<div class="dropdown gradient">` ,
        so should be now  `<div class="dropdown>`